# Developing spotify apps under Windows 7 64Bit - Application keys

Tags: windows-7, spotify

I have a perfect developer account now, copied the 32bit file libspotify.dll to SYSWOW64. I have the developer menu in my spotify client. When I try to open the inspector, a blue message appears: "choose the app you wanna inspect". I try to inspect a random app, but nothing happens. To develop my own, or try the examples I need an application key. But the form doesn't seem to do anything: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/#application-keys

Am I missing sth.?

Spotifiy client version: 0.8.2.610.g090a06f8

The console does not reveal anything. Hotkey for the console: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd>

Comment: I guess this is unrelated to your problem, but if the *libspotify.dll* is a 32-bit library, it should reside in the **SysWOW64** directory in 64-bit Windows installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libSpotify is for embedding Spotify tech into your own standalone application. If you're developing a HTML app to go inside the Spotify client, you don't need libSpotify or a libSpotify application key.

As for inspecting apps, you're only allowed to inspect your own applications. To get started, check out the documentation [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/) and the tutorial [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/tutorial/).

Comment: Great! You just lifted my confusion!